# Vertices of a shrinkwrapped plane show seprate from the shrinkwrapped face

Tags: shrinkwrap

I'm a beginner in blender and trying to create a scene with boat on the ocean waves. I used a plane mesh for the ocean modifier and added other plane for the object to float into. I used shrinkwrap for the other plane and tried to set the "copy location" constraint to the boat but the boat always floats above the waves, i switched from object mode to edit mode and found out the vertices of the shrinkwrapped mesh to be floating above the shrinkwrapped face. Is there any solution?

[image: Image showing the vertices seprate from the same plane shrinkwrapped]

Comment: Please provide images.

Comment: Could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Can't share the file but could you resolve the problem from the image?

Comment: If you are in Edit mode it will show you the original mesh shape, if you want to see the mesh as transformed by the modifier you need to activate the On Cage option of the modifier, but is it your only problem here?

Comment: No the main problem is the boat. I want the boat to move with the waves with "copy location" constraint but the boat attaches to the original vertices instead of the mesh shrinkwrapped on the waves.

Comment: You need to create a vertex group for Plane.001 (select all the vertices and Ctrl G) and in the Copy Location select this vertex group, otherwise the boat will only follow the original mesh

Comment: I tried that too but the vertices still don't follow the waves. I was following youtube tutorials but this problem arises even when i follow the same settings as youtube videos suggest.

Comment: The 'Copy location' constrain is copying the position of the origin of the plane. The shrinkwrap modifier is only altering the position of the vertices of the plane, not it's origin. I'm not sure how you'd go about doing what you want to do but I can tell you this won't work for that.

Comment: Any solution for that?

Comment: It should work, why can't you share the file? Just replace the boat by a cube...

Comment: But thanks for suggestions

Comment: I think I see the same tutorial you have followed. They have the shrink-wrap mod set to nearest surface, not project. For project maybe enable the Z axis specifically

Comment: I guess the video had blender version 3.2 and i have version 3.6 so there may have been changes since the video dropped

Comment: The only problem I see from your image is that the plane is a bit too large, scale it down and see if it works, but if you are not in front of your computer....

Comment: Nope scale doesn't work too

Comment: How do you know if you can't test? Please share the file...

Comment: I tried to resolve this by tweaking a lot of settings and they didn't work that's why i know it

Comment: So please share the file when you'll be able, it's a bit hard to solve your problem if you and we can't test   ;)

Comment: it asks for an authorization

Comment: Try the new link

Comment: OK it was because you didn't assigned any vertex to the vertex group, a bit hard to guess without the file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No vertices were assigned to the vertex group called *SHRINKWRAP*, so select *Plane.001*, switch to *Edit* mode, select all and assign the vertices to the vertex group:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for help, forgot to assign the vertices.